# Timer module on HSC08

Tags: timer, embedded, microcontroller, pwm

I am using a MC9S08LH64 microcontroller's timer module to generate an internal timer for synchronization.
bus clock is at 4.3 MHz, modulo is set at 4309 (TPM1MODH and TPM1MODL) and I am expecting pulse every 1.25 ms but the result is about every 3.75ms.
Is there any setting I am missing here? Thank you very much

```
 /*
 * TPM1SC: pg 358
    bit 
    7   TOF need to check for this flag
    6       not used since no interrupt being used
    5   1  not used
    4   0  selecting bus clock
    3   1
    2   0  not dividing clock down
    1   0
    0   0
 */ 

TPM1SC = 0x08;
```

*Update:
I have just realized that changing the TPM1MOD has no effect on the result pulse width. TPM1SC is the only register I used to set up the module. Is there any other register I need to set up for this?

Here are the source code to set up the timer:

```
//to set up the modulo register:
void set_base_pulse(float time_ms){
int modulo_value;
modulo_value = (int) time_ms*1000/233;
TPM1MODH = modulo_value >>8;
TPM1MODL = modulo_value;
}
```

to generate the pulses, I checked the TOF flag, every 40 times the flag goes off, I toggle the output:

```
for(counter = 0; counter<40; counter++
{

   while(!TPM1SC_TOF){}
   if(counter ==40) output~=output;
}
```

Comment: You should post the code, reduced to the minimum showing the problem. How do you create the result pulse?

Comment: As jeb has suggestion, it would be a good idea if you could post the relevant code your executing on your microcontroller - if only to make it pretty obvious this is indeed a programming question (which I agree that it is). At the moment your post looks like a pure hardware question. We also have another site that might be of interest: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ - if you get no joy answer-wise then I could migrate your question over to electronics.SE. If this question does get closed then please @ reply me to re-open.

Comment: This has nothing to do with electronics, unless the poster plans to open up the QFP and manually re-bond the wires of the MCU. But indeed, If the OP gets no answer about his programming question from a programmer site, then they would look most likely look elsewhere and forgot that they ever came here. So please don't try to close posts because you are some random Joe who clicked past the question by mistake and doesn't understand a thing of what's being said.

Comment: I posted more codes, the rest of the code is for other features so I think they are irrelevant. I just want to set up a timer, count how many times that counter goes off, then toggle the output to create pulses.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments about the code:

> void set_base_pulse(float time_ms){

It is most often a very bad idea to use float numbers on 8-bit microcontrollers. The code generated will be extremely inefficient. In this case, I very much doubt you need them.

> (int) time_ms*1000/233;

What is the magic number 233? First of all define it to something that makes sense, `#define BUSCLOCK_ns 233` or similar. Also, your logic is flawed: 1.25 * 1000 / 233 = 5.36. Typecast this to int and you get 5. That's quite the difference.

> for(counter = 0; counter<40; counter++

Why do you burn away time in a loop? Can't you place the counting inside an ISR? TOF flag can give you an interrupt. Or better yet, use the built-in output compare/PWM function in the hardware.

> if(counter ==40) output~=output;

This is not valid C and will not compile. You probably meant `output = ~output`. Please post the real code that you have compiled, instead of typing something on the flight.

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow your expectation of 1,25ms, as 1/4.3E6MHz=233ns BUSCLK

If you set TPM1MOD to 4309 you should get a period of 233ns*4309=1,002ms.

But if you set TPM1MOD to 0x4309 (hex 0x4309=dez 17161) then you should get a period of 233ns*17161=3,99ms.

**EDIT: After your edit, showing the code**

It's, it's ... uncommon

IMHO, the pure timer settings will work, perhaps it's a bit inaccurate.

But the code to create your output signal is a bit odd.

Try it with something simple.

```
while (1)
{
   output = TPM1SC_TOF;
}
```

or to create a square signal

```
while (1)
{
   if ( TPM1SC_TOF )
     output = !output;
}
```

Comment: I set it to decimal, not hex 4309. TPM1MODH = 0x10, TPM1MODL = 0xD5.

Comment: For the timer, i let user select the time interval(1.25ms) then divide that by 233ns to get the mod value of 4309. The outcome is only 1ms because of the trim off when converting from double to int to write to TPM1MODH and TPM1MODL.

Comment: @user1604121:  That comment just makes it more important that you post the code.  Multiply the user input by 1E6 and work in microseconds to avoid such inaccuracies.  There is hardly any point in accepting non-integer input otherwise.

Comment: I posted more codes, the rest of the code is for other features so I think they are irrelevant. I just want to set up a timer, count how many times that counter goes off, then toggle the output to create pulses